# Finding zeros of polynomial given a complex zero

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am trying to find all the zeros of the following polynomial:

$P(x) = 2x^4-5x^3+21x^2+11x+91$

But I am already given one zero, that being $x=2-3i$.

Normally, this question would not be an issue, but the complex is throwing me right off, and I have no idea where to start. I am pretty sure all I need is a bump in the right direction and I would be able to solve the remaining problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex roots always come in pairs, so $x=2+3i$ must also be a zero and hence the quadratic $x^2-4x+13$ is a factor. Factoring gives $P(x) = (x^2-4x+13)(2x^2+3x+7)$. One can find the roots of $2x^2+3x+7$ using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Oh that's right, complex conjugates are also roots when their counterpart is a root. So indeed x=2+3i is also a zero. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: One more question, how did you manage to get the quadratic x^2-4x+13? Surely it isn't by multiplying the complex numbers together as that would give us 13...

Comment: I simply used the fact that the sum of the two roots of the monic polynomial $x+bx+c$ is always $-b$ and the product of the roots $c$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. If a polynomial with real coefficients has a complex root then the complex conjugate is also a root. Then you have two roots and a quadratic real factor.

Comment: While I already saw another answer with a further solution, this would've been the only hint I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. When I answer I try to guess the right amount of  minimal information - just enough to get you over a hump.

Answer (score 1):

One idea you could use is that if a complex number is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients, then the complex conjugate is also a root to the polynomial. This means that 2+3i is another root to the polynomial. You can now attempt to factorize the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two zeroes: $2 + 3i$ and $2 - 3i$ because complex zeros always come in a pair of complex conjugates. Which means, you now have:

$$[x - (2 - 3i)][x - (2 + 3i)]$$

Expand this you get

$$(x^2 -4x + 13)$$

Then use this as a divisor to your original polynomial.

Side note: By Descarte’s Rule of Signs, both $P(x)$ and $P(-x)$ have two sign changes. How many zeros do you think are there?